# Prevent content from automatically centering in grid with implicit rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid layout with implicit rows. I have used `calc(100vh)` as height so as to make one of the parts of `grid` as scrollable rather than overflowing.

[image: Scrollable when <code>content</code> is > 100vh]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.statement {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, auto) minmax(300px, 400px) minmax(400px, auto) minmax(300px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh);
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}

.header-navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #797d89;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3a3f51;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide-username {
  display: none;
}

.header-username {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee5e7;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f7f9f9;
}

.statement-list {
  grid-column: 2 /3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="statement">
  <div class="header-navbar">The Header</div>
  <div class="header-username hide-username">Header username</div>
  <div class="statement-list">
    <ul>
      <li>ABCD</li>
      <li>EFGH</li>
      <li>IJKL</li>
      <li>MNOP</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus
      leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit
      in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>

    <p>Etiam vitae sem venenatis, cursus enim sit amet, feugiat diam. Nullam orci lorem, pulvinar id rhoncus at, cursus in nulla. Maecenas eu sapien metus. Nam non elementum justo, vitae aliquet augue. Nam vestibulum purus ut tincidunt iaculis. Sed et sodales
      erat. In aliquam vestibulum urna sit amet egestas. Maecenas euismod sem metus, ut rutrum sapien lobortis et. Morbi efficitur sem semper, tincidunt justo eget, sagittis diam. Vestibulum vitae sapien tincidunt, fermentum tortor vulputate, dapibus
      ipsum.</p>

    <p>Mauris at sollicitudin turpis. Nullam varius nulla felis, sed aliquam diam lobortis in. Curabitur imperdiet tincidunt tellus eget dictum. Phasellus vestibulum scelerisque quam, eu finibus purus ultricies vel. Mauris consectetur vitae eros ac elementum.
      Phasellus sed vehicula tortor. Quisque magna eros, semper nec nisi a, suscipit vulputate tortor. In nisl elit, iaculis quis leo ac, iaculis malesuada enim. Suspendisse eleifend aliquet dolor, et molestie dolor varius eget. Fusce volutpat ornare
      eleifend.</p>

    <p>Proin congue, purus id lacinia tempor, nisi massa accumsan mi, sed aliquet nisi eros nec purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vulputate purus id rhoncus ultricies. Phasellus tristique
      hendrerit consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ultricies diam lorem, ut sodales quam suscipit nec. Proin vulputate ex venenatis, maximus tellus non, posuere risus. Curabitur
      ut tempus urna. Curabitur fermentum in sem sit amet molestie. Vivamus ligula velit, maximus sit amet diam et, egestas euismod ipsum. Suspendisse rutrum ante sagittis gravida eleifend. Nam sit amet lacinia quam. Duis eget feugiat odio, ut convallis
      metus.</p>

    <p>Nam a odio et ex dignissim finibus. Morbi accumsan ex ex, in convallis urna accumsan id. Ut faucibus eget tellus et feugiat. Curabitur condimentum ligula laoreet finibus fermentum. Cras vitae elementum dui. Suspendisse vel mollis dui. Aenean eleifend
      eros vel erat luctus, a maximus diam egestas. Nam et scelerisque mauris. Donec vitae interdum nunc. Nam suscipit ac eros id semper. Fusce pulvinar, dolor vitae congue interdum, justo elit consectetur est, vel luctus ex dolor a erat. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque ut libero rutrum, viverra ex in, congue mi. In eu iaculis nisl, nec suscipit ante. Praesent lorem nulla, luctus pretium metus vel, malesuada euismod erat. Mauris scelerisque mi felis, eu
      hendrerit nisi mattis ut.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus
      leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit
      in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>

    <p>Etiam vitae sem venenatis, cursus enim sit amet, feugiat diam. Nullam orci lorem, pulvinar id rhoncus at, cursus in nulla. Maecenas eu sapien metus. Nam non elementum justo, vitae aliquet augue. Nam vestibulum purus ut tincidunt iaculis. Sed et sodales
      erat. In aliquam vestibulum urna sit amet egestas. Maecenas euismod sem metus, ut rutrum sapien lobortis et. Morbi efficitur sem semper, tincidunt justo eget, sagittis diam. Vestibulum vitae sapien tincidunt, fermentum tortor vulputate, dapibus
      ipsum.</p>

    <p>Mauris at sollicitudin turpis. Nullam varius nulla felis, sed aliquam diam lobortis in. Curabitur imperdiet tincidunt tellus eget dictum. Phasellus vestibulum scelerisque quam, eu finibus purus ultricies vel. Mauris consectetur vitae eros ac elementum.
      Phasellus sed vehicula tortor. Quisque magna eros, semper nec nisi a, suscipit vulputate tortor. In nisl elit, iaculis quis leo ac, iaculis malesuada enim. Suspendisse eleifend aliquet dolor, et molestie dolor varius eget. Fusce volutpat ornare
      eleifend.</p>

    <p>Proin congue, purus id lacinia tempor, nisi massa accumsan mi, sed aliquet nisi eros nec purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vulputate purus id rhoncus ultricies. Phasellus tristique
      hendrerit consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ultricies diam lorem, ut sodales quam suscipit nec. Proin vulputate ex venenatis, maximus tellus non, posuere risus. Curabitur
      ut tempus urna. Curabitur fermentum in sem sit amet molestie. Vivamus ligula velit, maximus sit amet diam et, egestas euismod ipsum. Suspendisse rutrum ante sagittis gravida eleifend. Nam sit amet lacinia quam. Duis eget feugiat odio, ut convallis
      metus.</p>

    <p>Nam a odio et ex dignissim finibus. Morbi accumsan ex ex, in convallis urna accumsan id. Ut faucibus eget tellus et feugiat. Curabitur condimentum ligula laoreet finibus fermentum. Cras vitae elementum dui. Suspendisse vel mollis dui. Aenean eleifend
      eros vel erat luctus, a maximus diam egestas. Nam et scelerisque mauris. Donec vitae interdum nunc. Nam suscipit ac eros id semper. Fusce pulvinar, dolor vitae congue interdum, justo elit consectetur est, vel luctus ex dolor a erat. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque ut libero rutrum, viverra ex in, congue mi. In eu iaculis nisl, nec suscipit ante. Praesent lorem nulla, luctus pretium metus vel, malesuada euismod erat. Mauris scelerisque mi felis, eu
      hendrerit nisi mattis ut.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus
      leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit
      in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>

    <p>Etiam vitae sem venenatis, cursus enim sit amet, feugiat diam. Nullam orci lorem, pulvinar id rhoncus at, cursus in nulla. Maecenas eu sapien metus. Nam non elementum justo, vitae aliquet augue. Nam vestibulum purus ut tincidunt iaculis. Sed et sodales
      erat. In aliquam vestibulum urna sit amet egestas. Maecenas euismod sem metus, ut rutrum sapien lobortis et. Morbi efficitur sem semper, tincidunt justo eget, sagittis diam. Vestibulum vitae sapien tincidunt, fermentum tortor vulputate, dapibus
      ipsum.</p>

    <p>Mauris at sollicitudin turpis. Nullam varius nulla felis, sed aliquam diam lobortis in. Curabitur imperdiet tincidunt tellus eget dictum. Phasellus vestibulum scelerisque quam, eu finibus purus ultricies vel. Mauris consectetur vitae eros ac elementum.
      Phasellus sed vehicula tortor. Quisque magna eros, semper nec nisi a, suscipit vulputate tortor. In nisl elit, iaculis quis leo ac, iaculis malesuada enim. Suspendisse eleifend aliquet dolor, et molestie dolor varius eget. Fusce volutpat ornare
      eleifend.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when the height of the `grid-item` that is supposed to be scrollable is smaller and the total height of the page becomes less than `calc(100vh)`, the `grid-item` comes in the middle of the page rather than being aligned at the top.

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.statement {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, auto) minmax(300px, 400px) minmax(400px, auto) minmax(300px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh);
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}

.header-navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #797d89;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3a3f51;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide-username {
  display: none;
}

.header-username {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee5e7;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f7f9f9;
}

.statement-list {
  grid-column: 2 /3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="statement">
  <div class="header-navbar">The Header</div>
  <div class="header-username hide-username">Header username</div>
  <div class="statement-list">
    <ul>
      <li>ABCD</li>
      <li>EFGH</li>
      <li>IJKL</li>
      <li>MNOP</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus
      leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit
      in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>

    <p>Etiam vitae sem venenatis, cursus enim sit amet, feugiat diam. Nullam orci lorem, pulvinar id rhoncus at, cursus in nulla. Maecenas eu sapien metus. Nam non elementum justo, vitae aliquet augue. Nam vestibulum purus ut tincidunt iaculis. Sed et sodales
      erat. In aliquam vestibulum urna sit amet egestas. Maecenas euismod sem metus, ut rutrum sapien lobortis et. Morbi efficitur sem semper, tincidunt justo eget, sagittis diam. Vestibulum vitae sapien tincidunt, fermentum tortor vulputate, dapibus
      ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it such that even when the content doesn't occupy the entire page, it should be aligned at the top-part of the page.

Comment: I had used something like calc(100vh - 10px) before but removed it while posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many different solutions. One would be to restrict the height of the first row to the height of the header, 50px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.statement {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, auto) minmax(300px, 400px) minmax(400px, auto) minmax(300px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh);
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto; /* new */
}

.header-navbar {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #797d89;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3a3f51;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

.hide-username {
    display: none;
}

.header-username {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    margin-top: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee5e7;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f7f9f9;
}

.statement-list {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="statement">
    <div class="header-navbar">The Header</div>
    <div class="header-username hide-username">Header username</div>
    <div class="statement-list">
   <ul>
     <li>ABCD</li>
     <li>EFGH</li>
     <li>IJKL</li>
     <li>MNOP</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>

      <p>Etiam vitae sem venenatis, cursus enim sit amet, feugiat diam. Nullam orci lorem, pulvinar id rhoncus at, cursus in nulla. Maecenas eu sapien metus. Nam non elementum justo, vitae aliquet augue. Nam vestibulum purus ut tincidunt iaculis. Sed et sodales erat. In aliquam vestibulum urna sit amet egestas. Maecenas euismod sem metus, ut rutrum sapien lobortis et. Morbi efficitur sem semper, tincidunt justo eget, sagittis diam. Vestibulum vitae sapien tincidunt, fermentum tortor vulputate, dapibus ipsum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The property that controls the size of implicit rows is [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows). Its initial value is `auto`.

With `grid-auto-rows: auto` you can expect tracks [in various scenarios](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto), such as this one, to stretch out across the container, similar to `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`. That can result in grid items that appear vertically centered.

The simple solution is to override the default with `grid-auto-rows: min-content`.

```css
.statement {
  grid-auto-rows: min-content; /* NEW */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, auto) minmax(300px, 400px) minmax(400px, auto) minmax(300px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh);
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}

.header-navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #797d89;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3a3f51;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide-username {
  display: none;
}

.header-username {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee5e7;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f7f9f9;
}

.statement-list {
  grid-column: 2 /3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="statement">
  <div class="header-navbar">The Header</div>
  <div class="header-username hide-username">Header username</div>
  <div class="statement-list">
    <ul>
      <li>ABCD</li>
      <li>EFGH</li>
      <li>IJKL</li>
      <li>MNOP</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vehicula mi non risus dignissim pulvinar. Integer sed lacus vitae enim sagittis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed quis nunc eget nibh facilisis condimentum. Proin imperdiet faucibus
      leo, ut ullamcorper dui sollicitudin id. Sed gravida felis id turpis auctor, sit amet suscipit diam euismod. Curabitur egestas ex ligula, in tincidunt ex sollicitudin eget. Sed sodales tincidunt fermentum. Vivamus at leo eu mauris congue suscipit
      in in felis. Praesent a consequat nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With `grid-auto-rows: min-content;` only when the content is less than 100vh does it work. When it goes above that, the content becomes unscrollable. I looked into [the mozdev css grid examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows#Syntax) and used something like this - `grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, min-content);` and it seems to work. I don't know if this is the right way.

Comment: That looks like a good adjustment. Test it across all your targeted browsers.